# ERC20 Token transfer keeps failing

Tags: transactions, failed-transaction

I am trying to transfer USDC from my metamask wallet to binance but my transaction has now failed 5 times. Please help me out my funds are stuck.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x86985799e234a9b7e7dd2198404c498e82d78e5df5adb124887eebba56246890

Comment: you are not giving it enough gas

Answer (score 1):

You have the sufficient balance to transfer. Try with high gas limit.
Refer here to know the current gas price : https://etherscan.io/gastracker

Answer (score 1):

You only provided 43,348 gas for the transaction, which is not sufficient.

Increase the gas amount (NOT the gas price) in Metamask to 100000 and it will work.